# Undeclared identifier in VS 2008 - Singelton (very basic)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, null, int, undeclared-identifier

I am currently working on a school project that uses the old VS2008 with essentially little to no error assistance. Anyways, I am trying to learn about Singeltons and was trying to create as basic as it goes. But suddenly from nowhere I am getting errors. Am I that blind or what am I doing wrong?
Error:

```
1>.\Source\Singelton.cpp(3) : error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Source\Singelton.cpp(12) : error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Source\Singelton.cpp(21) : error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Source\Singelton.cpp(26) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
1>.\Source\Singelton.cpp(30) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
```

Complete code:
header:

```
#ifndef __SINGELTON_H__
#define __SINGELTON_H__


class Singelton
{
private:
    static Singelton* instance;
    Singelton();
    int value;
public:
    ~Singelton();
    int get_value();
    void set_value(int v);
    static Singelton* getInstance();

};
#endif
```

.cpp

```
#include "Singelton.h"

Singelton* Singelton::instance = NULL;

Singelton::Singelton()
{
    value=0;
}

Singelton* Singelton::getInstance()
{
    if (instance == NULL)
    {
        instance = new Singelton();
    }
    return instance;
}

Singelton::~Singelton()
{
    instance = NULL;
}

int get_value()
{
    return value;
}
void set_value(int v)
{
    value=v;
}
```

Comment: Add `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: And add scope to get_value and set_value (`int Singleton::get_value()`).

Comment: @HansPassant: `<cstddef>` would be more appropriate, since that's where `NULL` is defined. (Or possibly `<stddef.h>`, if you really want to use the deprecated C headers for some reason).

Comment: Hmm, that ought to make *nullptr* appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
```

You haven't included `<cstddef>`, which defines `NULL`.

```
error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
```

You forgot to include the class name when you defined the member functions, so instead declared new non-member functions:

```
int Singelton::get_value()
{// ^^^^^^^^^^^
    return value;
}
```

You should also spell "singleton" properly and avoid [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `__SINGELTON_H__`. Hopefully, you'll soon be taught why singletons are a bad idea in general, and doubly so in C++. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975), in case your teacher forgets to cover that.